# multi word href link placing words on top of each other in HTML/CSS?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

This is kinda hard to describe on the question title, but basically I am setting up a link that is from my mysql database.

When I print out the link here is an example of what is happening:

Link is in a table cell.

**Red**

**Bull**

Here is what I am trying to do:
 **Red Bull**

For some reason any multi-word links are putting the words on top of each other.
I have tried:

CSS a:

```
display: inline- block; 
dislay: inline;
```

I've tried setting up a width, maybe the table cell was limiting the link space, but its not working either.

Even worse for my little issue here is the fact that the jsfiddle is working perfectly fine. http://jsfiddle.net/68xSj/ at least you can see what I am basically trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Literally just found the answer to this issue.
I'm not sure if this is on mysql serverside end or on how css reacts to a php call.

Basically, on mysql database I had written the "itemName" as eg. `Red Bull`.
when I made the php call in the second Cell div for some reason it placed Red on top of Bull as a link. To fix it, (i tried this right after posting) I simply had itemName =
    `Red&nbspBull`.
This fixed the little bug.

As we all know `&nbsp;` is a space in html, mysql pastes this into html and walaa.